# How to save the value of a Yes/No Checkbox via Sharepoint 2016 REST API onPrem?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, rest, api

How do you save checked/unchecked for sharepoint 2016 on-prem via the REST api?  I have a couple input text boxes saving text, but I'm can't save yes/no for cbAttending, I can't seem to get the value when it's checked.  Appreciate any pointers.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="cbAttending" value="" />Attending?
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>


<script>
function addNew() {
        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.NewListItem" },
            "Title": $('#Field1').val(),
            "Type": $('#Field2').val(),
            "Attending": $('#cbAttending).val()
              };

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Items",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("item added...");
                },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with SharePoint.

The correct way to get the "value" of a checkbox (i.e. whether it is checked or not) using jQuery is

```
$('#cbAttending').prop('checked') // will output true if checked, false if unchecked
```

or (the older way)

```
$('#cbAttending').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see there is a `'` missing in your jQuery selector.

It should be like:

```
"Attending": $('#cbAttending').val()
```

Also, I would suggest that before directly using `.val()` in `data` you can check what you value you are getting from it by adding it in `console.log()`.

So that you will know what are getting from this expression.

If you are not getting proper values using this expression then check below stack overflow link. There are so many answers provided. You can try the combination and see which one fits your needs:

[Get checkbox value in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834350/get-checkbox-value-in-jquery).

Including:

```
$('#checkboxId').is(':checked')
```

**OR**

```
$('#checkboxId').prop('checked')
```

**OR**

```
$('#checkboxId').attr('checked')
```

**OR**

```
$('#checkboxId')[0].checked
```